# Select random object from list c#

Tags: random

I am making a black jack game (more complicated than it needs to be) and I believe I have setup a Dealer class, and then a game class which has a list of Dealers from in it. see below.

Dealer Class

```
namespace BlackJackClassLibrary
{
    public class Dealer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Endurance { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Game Class

```
namespace BlackJackClassLibrary
{
    public class Game
    {
        public List<Dealer> Dealers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And then finally I have a method in my Program which adds dealers to the delaers list like so.

```
    public void SetupData()
    {
        game.Dealers.Add(new Dealer { Name = "Bill", Endurance = 5 });
        game.Dealers.Add(new Dealer { Name = "John", Endurance = 3 });
        game.Dealers.Add(new Dealer { Name = "Johnny", Endurance = 2 });
        game.Dealers.Add(new Dealer { Name = "Robert", Endurance = 1 });
    {
```

How can I now randomly select a dealer from this list of dealers?

Comment: You could always just generate a random number to use as an index for the list

Answer (score 2):

Already mentioned in the comments, but to provide an example - use a random number generator.

```
var random = new Random();
```

Use it to select a dealer.

```
var dealer = game.Dealers[random.Next(0, 4)];
```

Comment: The only reason I didn't write an answer is because I was sure there was a `Collection.Random()` method